# Having problems outputting proper CGI, Python script?

Tags: python, server, cgi

So I am trying to keep my project as simple as possible, therefore I have decided to use a CGI with my Python scripts in order to run a program that does something.

So here is my current setup:

In CMD, I run:
`python -m http.server --cgi 8000`

This start a server for me. I can access it via `localhost:8000`.

Next, I am trying to find my directory with the script by typing in the actual address where it is located: `localhost:8000/test/cgi-bin/test.py`

This is giving me the output of the actual file, not actually reading it properly. I have tried 2 different ways to output data on the Python file, for example:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Content-type: text\html \r\n\r\n")
sys.stdout.write("<html><title>Hi</title><body><p>This is a test</p></body></html>")
```

and

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print("<!doctype html><title>Hello</title><h2>hello world</h2>")
```

Both of which result in the actual code being displayed in my browser.

A few questions:

- How do I get my server to automatically take me to the location of the file I am trying to run?
- How do I get the python script to output the proper stuff?
- Am I setting this up correctly?

I am trying to avoid installing any new dependencies and keep it as minimal as possible.

I am running on Python3, Windows7. I am trying to avoid downloading more pip packages and dependencies because my work is very tech precautious.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to say that writing plain CGI-scripts in 2017 is a way of a brave person. Your life will be much easier if you would use [bottle](http://bottlepy.org) or flask.

But if you want, here is the way you can start.

1. `python -m http.server --cgi` assumes that the `cgi-bin` is in the current directory. That is you should go to the `test` directory and start the command from there. And then call `http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test.py`.
2. Your cgi-script is not correct. The script should be executable. I am not sure if it needs a shebang line in Windows when you run the `http.server`, but is is required when you run CGI-scripts with Apache web server under Windows. The shebang line starts with `#!` and then contains the full path to python3 interpreter, and the line should end with `\n` and not `\r\n`, otherwise it won't work.

   After that you should output all the HTTP-headers, print a blank line, and output your content. All HTTP-headers should be separated by '\r\n' and not '\n'.

Here is an example CGI-script that works on OS X:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
sys.stdout.write('Status: 200 OK\r\n')
sys.stdout.write('Content-type: text/html;charset="utf-8"\r\n\r\n')

print('<h1>Hello, world!</h1>')
```

Comment: `http.server` doesn't assume `cgi-bin` is the current directory. It rather assumes that the CGI script will be put in a subfolder named `/cgi-bin` (or `/htbin` according to the docs). This is why he either has to move his CGI scipts in a `/cgi-bin` subfolder or add `/test` in the `cgi_directories` variable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [http.server documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler)

> This defaults to ['/cgi-bin', '/htbin'] and describes directories to treat as containing CGI scripts.

So, `http.server` is expecting to find CGI scripts in a subfolder named **/cgi-bin** ot **/htbin** in your python.exe folder. If you really want to use the test folder, then change the `cgi-directories` variable in the `http/server.py` script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first line of the script needs to specify the interpreter path. Some examples are:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/bin/python2.3
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
#!c:\Python24\python.exe
#!c:\Python25\python.exe
```

See if it helps.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: So like, find where my Python is located and then write that up top?

Comment: So, I added the path of my Python to the code, but I receive an error message as so: `Error response

Error code: 404

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.` in my browser.

Comment: This is my path: `#!C:\Users\BregmanM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe`

Comment: Now I reran it and it's still just outputting the exact code on file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the extension if you are in a macos environment, so it is handled as an executable file instead of a script. Worked for me.